# Color some samples of MATLAB figure with different color

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a discrete signal x of length N traced in MATLAB using the command

```
stem(abs(x)); axis([0 N+6 0 4]);
```

The resulted figure is shown below:

[image]

My question I need only some values corresponding for example to index [7 10 11 12 15 18 48 50 52 60] to be colored with different color , let's say with red.
How can I do that into my figure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Multiple Plots by `hold on` and Matrix Indexing

You could possibly and alternatively place a plot on top of plot by using `hold on`. This does require an adjustment where you need a vector in this case `Sample` and `Indices` which specify the sample number/data point index. You can also use matrix indexing to get the amplitude/data points corresponding to the key point, `Indicies`.

[image: Using Two Plots]

```
%Vector relating to the sample/data point number%
Sample = linspace(1,70,70);

%Random test data%
X = randi([0,2],1,70);
stem(Sample,X);

hold on
%Key indices to change colour%
Key_Indices = [7 10 11 12 15 18 48 50 52 60];

%Matrix indexing to get values/amplitudes corresponding to key indices%
X_Prime = X(Key_Indices);

stem(Key_Indices,X_Prime,'r');

axis([0 70 0 3]);
hold off
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Answer (score 0):

This code makes just the circles red and not the stems

[plot with selected red circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg2rq.png)

```
%Vector relating to the sample/data point number
Sample = linspace(1,70,70);

%Random test data
X = randi([0,2],1,70);
stem(Sample,X);

%Key indices to change color
Key_Indices = [7 10 11 12 15 18 48 50 52 60];

line(Sample(Key_Indices), X(Key_Indices), 'linestyle', 'none', 'marker', 'o', 'color', 'r')

axis([0 70 0 3])
grid on
```